# CCParticleSystem and TestFlight build bug?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, particle-system, particles

I'm not really sure if this question is answerable as I am completely puzzled by this. Maybe if someone had a similar issue and can maybe point something out?

So I used 4 different CCParticleSystem effects in my app which run perfectly fine when built and installed from xcode. However, when I build and upload for testflight and download to my device, one of the CCParticleSystem effects doesn't show up with the intended particle texture, but instead shows up as a square instead of the texture I provided.

All 3 other CCParticleSystem effects are working properly though, just not this one, which is puzzling me.

I used Particle Designer for all 4 particle effects.

Anyone have any issues like this? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Sounds like a missing resource.  Sometimes builds from XCode to device ignore resource deletions and updates.  I'd suggest doing an uninstall from the device, a clean in XCode, and then rebuilding to see if that makes the XCode build consistent with the TestFlight build.  If it doesn't, then maybe verify that your particle resource has been included in every build target that it should be, if you have multiple build targets.

Comment: wow that fixed my problem! Post it as a solution so you can get credit for an accepted solution!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience there are a couple of things that can cause issues like this:

1. There could be a resource missing from your build that was present in a previous build. Sometimes builds from XCode to device ignore resource deletions and updates.

   You can check for this by doing an uninstall from the device, a clean in XCode, and then rebuilding to see if that makes the XCode build consistent with the TestFlight build.
2. If that doesn't help, then check the target membership of your particle resource and verify that it has been included in every build target that it should be (if you have multiple build targets).

Note that as a general rule, it is a good idea to do a clean within XCode prior to building an archive for distribution.  This should ensure that the archive is always built using the latest sources and resource files.